# Why does the postman post request not send body variables?

Tags: http, curl, post

I am attempting to send a plain POST request via Postman. I did the same via Curl and my server sees it just fine. Here is the settings for the Body:

[image: POSTMAN, Plaintext POST body]

And here is the request in the console:

[image: POSTMAN console]

My express server is not seeing the body variables. With curl like this it does:

```
curl -X POST https://xxx.appspot.com -d "volume=123&content=foobar"
```

What do I need to change for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two examples are not equivalent, because with Postman you have `Content-Type: text/plain` header set, but sending data via `curl -d` option, sets `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. From `curl` manual page:

```
-d, --data <data>
              (HTTP MQTT) Sends the specified data in a POST  request  to  the
              HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has
              filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button. This  will
              cause curl to pass the data to the server using the content-type
              application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
```

I don't have any experience with Postman, but my guess would be you need to select `x-www-form-urlencoded` button instead of current `raw` button.

Comment: that was what was required.